# List all days between two defined is back same date PHP

Tags: php

I have try to list all days between two predefined, when i test on my server i have output like this belowe, as you can see 28.10 is two times there, but when i test this on phptester is back me normal output. What can be problem here? Where i have make mistake?

```
$from = strtotime('2018-10-25');
$to = strtotime('2018-10-30');
for ($i=$from; $i<=$to; $i+=86400)
    {
         $list[] = date('Y-m-d', $i);
    }
echo '<pre>';
print_r($list);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-10-25
    [1] => 2018-10-26
    [2] => 2018-10-27
    [3] => 2018-10-28
    [4] => 2018-10-28
    [5] => 2018-10-29
)
```

Comment: you get trapped because time changed on 28th... that day is 86400 + 3600 - perhaps you want to remplace $i+=... with $i = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $i) . ' + 1 day')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are running into the end of daylight savings time, when the clock gets set back an hour. So adding 24 hours worth of seconds on that day leaves you on the same day.

It's better to adjust time by days for example using the `DateTime` class:

```
$start = new DateTime('2018-10-25');
$end = new DateTime('2018-10-29');
while ($start <= $end) {
    $list[] = $start->format('Y-m-d');
    $start->modify('+1 day');
}
print_r($list);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-10-25
    [1] => 2018-10-26
    [2] => 2018-10-27
    [3] => 2018-10-28
    [4] => 2018-10-29
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Wmkc6)